# Black apple crumble!

Tags: apples

I used the apple crisp recipe from [Joy of Baking](http://www.joyofbaking.com/AppleCrisp.html) and I'm quite sure I followed it to the dot (didn't add blackberries, though, only apples). But for some reason, after I took it out, let it cool a little and cut into it, I saw that the apple had turned a strange purple/black color! These were perfectly good (not rotten or bruised) apples that I bought a few days ago. Any reason that this could have happened?

EDIT:
Here's a picture. I managed to salvage this one piece of cooked apple, since I had thrown out the rest of it - sorry for the crappy quality and excuse my face in the background! As you can see, half of it is tinged a strange purple/black!
[image]

Comment: What type of pan was it cooked in, aluminum magnesium by chance?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure - but I have used this pan multiple times to bake things!

Comment: Recipe says it has a cup of blackberries in it, could the color be from that?

Comment: Didn't add them! It contained only apples and walnuts.

Comment: How long a time passed between cutting the apples and making the filling? What variety of apple did you use? It's a little hard to tell based on the picture but the color seems to be mostly around the edges - it could be as simple as an exaggerated color from oxidation.

Answer (score 3):

Walnuts are most likely your culprit.  Black walnuts have more of this tendency than common cooking walnuts, but I have had it occur with both.  I especially have seen in with port chops stuffed with walnuts and applesauce getting a very purple stain to them.  I have seen multiple theories on why purple, but with walnut breads a common suggestion seems to be that iron reacts with the walnut to cause the purple, and some flours are higher in iron than others.

And idea, but just a suggestion, is toasting the walnuts first might reduce this tendency.  In fact, here is an article from Cook's Illustrated https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/6672-preventing-purple-walnut-bread.  They indicate that they believe it to be Gallic acid in the walnuts doing it, and that blanching for 1 minute before using them will reduce the effect.

ETA:  Looking up Gallic Acid was interesting.  It was used as a key ingredient in "Iron Gall Ink" in the 12th through 19th centuries as a standard writing and drawing ink, giving some idea of its ability to color.

Comment: Interesting! That might explain why cardamom powder can darken apple fillings more than it should by the green color alone (cardamom appears to have gallic acid and related compounds too...)

Comment: @rackandboneman I have always found the purple somewhat appealing, but have seen it go to black, which is not so much for me.  But have seen zero effect on taste.  I always knew walnuts were the source, but did not know the gallic acid part.  My first thoughts were tannin, which I guess gallic acid is!